# How to change correct battery in any TWS Airbuds Case?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, replacement

I have been using Truke Buds BTG3 (having 3.7 V 300 mAh battery in case) more than a year. Battery backup of the charging case got poor because of weak battery! So I am trying to replace it with a new one.

What my confusion is that how can I find the maximum battery capacity that can be added for the embedded PCB?

And can I use a larger capacity 3.7 V Lipo battery like 450 mAh or 950 mAh single cell batteries with varying **WH** safely. Since the built-in battery has 300 mAh with *1.11 Wh*, does this make a sense in upgrading battery?

And overall are there any challenges and risks in replacing battery which may leads to failure?

[image: Truke Buds BTG3 circuit board]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Comment: Probably fine with higher capacity. However, be _very_ careful with that spicy pillow. Accidentally poke it with your soldering iron and it may burst in flames and molten particles spewing out.

Comment: The problem most likely to ruin your improvement is that the charge controller may be programmed to count **charge** in and out of the battery and may shut off when it thinks "that's enough by now".

Comment: Do you think that the charge controller is programmed to a level by this newborn tws company?? But I wonder after the case gets charged, the charging light indication will be constant rather than blinking while in charge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a larger-capacity Li-ion battery. Just make sure it's the same voltage (3.6 or 3.7 V nominal) and that it includes a protector BMS (the little board you see at the end of the Li-ion cell).

In terms of risks:

- Be absolutely sure you don't short out the battery leads
- Be absolutely sure you connect the red wire to the positive pad, the black wire to the negative pad
- Enclose the Li-ion pouch cell in the enclosure in such way to contain its expansion (if any)

Comment: Thanks for your response And there is one more clarification in the first point that you warned about shorting the battery leads. I can't understand it could you specify clearly as I am a newbie in this thing

Comment: "And I wonder can we connect multiple batteries without any harm?" That's a different question. Please start a new question.